# Mapping ALT to Super in emacs

Tags: linux, macos, emacs

I am running Emacs under linux on a virtual machine in OSX.

I am trying to map alt key on the mac keyboard to super, I want this to only apply inside the virtual machine running linux.

Is it possible to do that within .emacs file only?

Comment: See [Emacs: How to Define Super ＆ Hyper Keys](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html "Emacs: How to Define Super ＆ Hyper Keys") and [Linux: Keyboard Tools for Key Layout, Keymapping, Keybinding](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_keyboard_tools.html).

Comment: When I am running under linux virtual box it doesnt recognize being "under MAC" so all these MAC defines wont work.

Comment: Are you running a GUI on the Linux machine, or are you talking about running Emacs in text mode via SSH in a Terminal or iTerm2 window?

Comment: running through terminal